# GridView not centering; aligned right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

**I can't figure out where this left padding is coming from.**

My grid is not just uncentered, it appears to be aligned to the right. What's up with this?

[image]

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:columnWidth="240dp"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:verticalSpacing="22dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent = "true">
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is coming from the line

```
android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
```

Remove that and test it out.

Comment: This fixes the right alignment issue! Now it's aligned to the right, which is at least less mysterious. By the looks of it, it's now using the "columnWidth" strategy.. is that the default? Any suggestions on how to get the spacingWidthUniform result without the strange alignment?

Comment: Yes That is the default. I am not sure how you would get spacingWidthUniform  without the alignment issue. I have generally kept it the columnWidth.

Comment: (Correction: "Now it's aligned to the left") I went with your approach and am allowing cells to stretch. Within each cell there are centered fixed-width elements. Doesn't look too bad.

Comment: Yes. That is exactly what I do as well. I make sure everything is align within the cell's xml and keep the columnWidth for my gird. Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tag

```
 android:gravity="center" in GridView
```

As

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="3"// Changed to 3
        android:columnWidth="60dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"// Added
        android:verticalSpacing="22dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
    </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This does not help, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm hesitant to set `numColumns` because this layout adjusts to different screen sizes and orientations. Using `columnWidth` makes the grid align to the right, but how can I get the even spacing back? I'd rather not stretch the cells..